# Qt Get item at offset from index

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am a noob at Qt and PyQt, I am looking for ideally an easy way to get an item index from a model that is "offset" from an index I already have. Below is an example of a tree data layout using QStandardItemModel and QStandardItems:

```
"Column 1"     | "Column 2"
 Parent 1      |  Count: 2
   --> Child 1
   --> Child 2
 Parent 2      |  Count: 3
   --> Child 1
   --> Child 2
   --> Child 3
```

It is easy for me to get the index of Parent items, but once I have that index, what is the best way to get the index of the "Count" item beside the Parent?

to date I have used basically the following code:
    `parent.parent().child(parent.row(),1)`

This seems very wrong though...

Comment: Do you specifically want an index (as in `QModelIndex`) or an item (as in `QStandardItem`)? And are you starting from a child index, or a child item? Also, is it necessary to navigate directly from a specific index/item, or could you use the methods of the model instead?

Comment: Parent is a QModelIndex, I believe my miss understanding was in the row property of sibling. I thought that it was like an offset and would be zero based with zero being the row of the current parent, therefore parent.sibling(0,1) would give me say "Count: 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QModelIndex::sibling()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#sibling) would allow to collapse your example a bit: `parent.sibling(parent.row(),1)`.